# How to pre-populate Form fields with initial values in Kinetise?

Tags: android, ios, mobile

In Kinetise mobile app generator I want to init form fields (like Text Input) with some dynamic (from web service) values. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself so I share it if someone have similar problem:

You need to put Form widget into List widget.

1. Add List widget and connect it to your API exposing those initial values
2. Reduce items count to 1, disable SHOW MORE
3. Add Form widget inside that single-item List widget.
4. edit TextInput of that Form widget and set its initial value being read from proper node of API you pointed to in step 1.

Initial values of other Form fields should be handled accordingly.